# AWS Basic Auth for EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-ec2

I have a small web service serving http traffic on an AWS EC2 instance.

I would like to add a layer of security, so that people need to authenticate in order to actually reach the service.

Something extremely simple even with password hard coded somewhere, just to don't let the web services completely exposed on the web.

What is the fastest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi @siscia, this should help -> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=57805 I've noticed questions on AWS are often not answered on SO. You'll have better luck in Amazon's forum

Comment: What tech did you implement the web service?

Comment: If you are using Apache use this steps https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @StephenZeng, it is in golang, however I don't want to change the implementation, I just want a thin layer on top of it.

Comment: @AndyK, it may helps, but not too much... Thanks though I was hoping in something a little easier...

Comment: @Siscia You can stand up Apache (or Nginx) as a reverse proxy in front of your Go app and set it to require basic auth. Other than modifying your Go app's source or that's probably the quickest method.

Comment: @jbird yeaah, that is what I was thinking too, but I was hoping that AWS provided something "fancier"

Comment: AWS doesn't provide anything like this. Apache or Nginx reverse proxy is your best option.

Comment: @Siscia I have no experience with this but you might can use the AWS API Gateway as an intermediate layer to provide authentication. It is likely more work than a simple reverse proxy but if an AWS-specific solution is desired it may be helpful. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html.

Comment: @jbird nono definitely I want something simple and easy, but I don't want something AWS specific. If AWS was able to provide me with something as easy as clicking a button I would have gone that way, now I prefer a simple reverse proxy